# Finding out the number of threads

Tags: windows, process

I need help please, can someone tell me how to know on how many threads a specific program is running?
I use Windows 10 and let's say the program is BlueStacks.

Comment: Do you mean programmatically, or you just want to know via some tool you can open?

Comment: If you mean some GUI tool, the Task Manager can do this. On the "Details" tab, right click any column header (like Name) and select "Choose Columns", then check "Threads". Now the Task Manager will show the number of threads.